# If global-max-size is hit address is blocked

Tags: activemq-artemis

I have this in my `broker.xml`:

```xml
...
<global-max-size>1Mb</global-max-size>
...
<address-setting match="MyQueue">
   <address-full-policy>BLOCK</address-full-policy>
   <max-size-bytes>50Mb</max-size-bytes>
</address-setting>
...
```

With this configuration I am observing that `MyQueue` will get blocked as soon as `global-max-size` is hit:

```
2021-07-07T17:53:16.678+02 WARN [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222038: Starting paging on address 'OtherQueue'; size is currently: 351,993 bytes; max-size-bytes: -1; global-size-bytes: 1,066,966
2021-07-07T17:53:16.704+02 WARN [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] AMQ222183: Blocking message production on address 'MyQueue'; size is currently: 662,049 bytes; max-size-bytes on address: 52,428,800, global-max-size is 1,100,882
```

Is this working as designed? If `global-max-size` is hit will all producers get blocked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is working as designed. When you hit `global-max-size` then the `address-full-policy` (i.e. `BLOCK` in your case) will be enforced on the address. See [the documentation](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/documentation/latest/paging.html#global-max-size) for more details.

For what it's worth, it doesn't make much sense to set `<global-max-size>1Mb</global-max-size>` and `<max-size-bytes>50Mb</max-size-bytes>`.